# Inlining private and protected virtual function calls

Tags: inheritance, compiler-optimization, jit, virtual-functions, crtp

Consider the following piece of C++ code:

```
class IFoo {
 public:
  virtual void Bar() const = 0;
};

template <typename Derived>
class AbstractFoo : public IFoo {
 public:
  void Bar() const override {
    int i = 0;
    auto derived = static_cast<const Derived *>(this);
    while (derived->ShouldBar(i++)) {
      derived->DoBar();
    }
  }
};

class FooImpl : public AbstractFoo<FooImpl> {
 private:
  bool ShouldBar(int i) const {
    return i < 10;
  }

  void DoBar() const {
    std::cout << "Bar!" << std::endl;
  }

  friend class AbstractFoo<FooImpl>;
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<IFoo> foo(new FooImpl());
  foo->Bar();
}
```

This is, of course, the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) with a slight twist: after the virtual method `Bar` is polymorphically dispatched once through the interface `IFoo`, calls to `ShouldBar` and `DoBar` remain static and may even be inlined. Were this implemented the other way, (`AbstractFoo` be non-generic and `ShouldBar` and `DoBar` private virtual methods), there would be two virtual function calls *every iteration*.

Situations were this kind of optimization opportunity matters include iterations schemes, such as [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [saturation](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45319-9_23) of huge state spaces. At some point of these algorithms, a concrete implementation has to make choices about in what direction to continue the search, whether to add the state to a result set, etc. Implemented polymorphically, these potentially result in millions of virtual calls to relatively tiny functions (some of them could even be empty!), which has a performance penalty even measurable by profiling. (Keep in mind that these iterative algorithms usually do no I/O, contrary to the toy example above.)

In languages without CRTP, the only alternative solution is the duplication of the "skeleton" of the iteration scheme. For example, in C#, this is not too painful, because we have partial methods:

```
interface IFoo {
  void Bar();
}

// This is copy-pasted for every IFoo implementation.
partial class FooImpl : IFoo {
  void Bar() {
    int i = 0;
    bool shouldBar = false;
    ShouldBar(i++, out shouldBar);
    while (shouldBar) {
      DoBar();
      ShouldBar(i++, out shouldBar);
    }
  }

  partial void ShouldBar(int i, out bool result);

  partial void DoBar();
}

partial class FooImpl {
  partial void ShouldBar(int i, our bool result) {
    result = i < 10;
  }

  partial void DoBar() {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar!");
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is still some awkwardness because partial methods must return `void`, and the code of abstract" class needs to be duplicated.

Are there any languages / runtime environments which can perform this optimization on simple virtual protected methods?

I think the problem boils down to the fact the *virtual public* methods should not have there machine code generated for each *implementation*, but for each *concrete class*. Thinking about a simple vtable, the slot in the vtable of `FooImpl` should not hold `AbstractFoo#Bar` in the slot of `IFoo#Bar`, but a specialized `FooImpl#Bar` with non-virtual / inlined calls to `ShouldBar` and `DoBar` generated by the JIT.

Are there any environments which are capable of performing this optimization, or at least some research in this directions?

Comment: Why looking for other languages, when you have all you need in C++ ?

Comment: While C++ is excellent for (nearly) zero-cost abstractions, things like the CRTP could hardly be called intuitive. Moreover, there are advantages of generational garbage collectors which cannot be easily simulated with RAII (e.g. amoritising away allocation and deallocation costs of small objects) and require a managed runtime. Although perharps, I would be better off going with C++/CLI... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a JIT, use the CPU's branch predictor. Any decent CPU will try to cache the target of each indirect branch instruction, so the cost of a correctly-predicted indirect branch is the same as a conditional branch, typically zero.

Optimizing this pattern is no different from the usual process of optimization. Your profiler should flag particular indirect branch instructions as a bottleneck. Optimize by dividing each slow instruction into several better-predictable ones, e.g.

```
if ( likely_to_be_FooImpl ) {
    foo->Bar();
} else {
    foo->Bar();
}
```

Preventing the compiler from eliminating the apparently superfluous branch is left as an exercise ;) . Or, ideally, one branch doesn't need an indirect dispatch at all:

```
if ( certain_to_be_FooImpl ) {
    static_cast< FooImpl * >( foo )->fooImpl::Bar();
} else {
    foo->Bar();
}
```

In any case, it would be a tall order for a JIT to look for correlations between local program state and the branch target. A JIT could notice that a branch tends to go to some particular destination, but the CPU already optimizes that case in hardware. Conversely, as long as the number of branches doesn't exceed the predictor's memory limit, spuriously indirect branches will be predicted away.